# Как переполнить тип int С++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Мне нужно отловить переполнение int не прибегая к математике.
Но как показала практика получить ошибку о переполнении нереально. После того как тип переполнен программа не выбрасывает исключение или ошибку, что бы ее можно было обработать.
Как посоветуете поступить?, вариант сравнения: если значение больше то сообщение об ошибке, не подходит.

Comment: Как я знаю это можно сделать с asm вместе. как сделано здесь http://www.firststeps.ru/mfc/steps/r.php?393 так как Ассамблер создает флаг при переполнении

Comment: Может быть лучше использовать template<typename T, typename E = _SAFEINT_DEFAULT_ERROR_POLICY> class SafeInt; - Extends the integer primitives to help prevent integer overflow and lets you compare different types of integers.

Answer (score 11):

Переполнение типа `int` [приводит к неопределенному поведению](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#4) (UB), и по этому в С++ программе его не может быть.

На практике, компилятор С++ может удалять код проверяющий переполнение `int`, т.к. переполнения не может происходить.

Если же переполнение `int` произойдет, то дальнейшее поведение программы не определено, и любые пост-фактум проверки бессмысленны, т.к. программа уже находится в невалидном состоянии.

По этому возможность переполнения можно проверить только до выполнения операции, которая может его вызвать, например:

```
int x;
if (x != INT_MAX) {
  ++x;
} else {
  // будет переполнение
}
```

Примечание:
На платформе x86 есть инструкция `into`, но она не доступна из С++.

---

В компиляторе gcc есть опция `-fstrict-overflow`, которая позволяет отключить оптимизации, связанные с невозможностью переполнения знаковых типов. Это позволяет компилировать старый код, нарушающий запрет на переполнение `int`. Впрочем в новом коде эту опцию лучше не использовать, и писать код, соответствующий требованиям стандарта.

Comment: Это если `int` по умолчанию знаковый, ЕМНИП. Ддя беззнакового `int` по стандарту wrap-around.

Comment: Хм. Не удержался и полез в стандарт. Нашёл 3.9.1/2. Век живи, век учись.

Comment: @Abyx  Где вы вычитали, что переполнение типа int приводит к UB?

Comment: @Abyx Есть некоторое противоречие в стандарте когда говорится что преобразование из одного типа в другой, когда исходный тип не умещается в результирующем, то это implementation-defined для знаковых типов.

Comment: Единственное, что на это хочется сказать -- "ф топку" такие стандарты и компиляторы.

Answer (score 2):

Для gcc есть вот [такие](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html) встроенные функции проверки переполнения

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/50131)

Comment: @Saidolim, Вы имели в виду запрос в гугл: `gcc overflow functions` ?