# Контроль переполнения

Tags: c++

В цикле совершаются действия над переменной типа `int`. В какой-то момент значение может превысить максимально допустимое. Как это проконтролировать?

Comment: Переполнение чего?

Comment: @aka47 Да, вопрос скудный. Лучше даже укажите, в каких именно условиях нужен контроль, кусок кода можно прикрепить.

Comment: @Abyx сделал.....

Comment: @aka47  Ну вот теперь понятнее. Действия, которые могут увеличить - это + и *.  Вообще можно попробовать отслеживать, сколько "осталось" до максимума и отсюда рассчитывать, сколько можно прибавить и на сколько умножить.

Comment: Переполнение может возникнуть практически от любой арифметической операции. Даже от деления (`MIN_INT / (-1)`). Нет, C++ не предоставляет возможностей для автоматического контроля.

Comment: @VladD придумался костыль - завести переменную int64 и на нее смотреть.

Comment: @АлексейСаровский: Ну да, так по идее будет работать. Но это придётся реально проверять после каждой (!) операции! То есть код `int result = x + y + z;` теперь будет выглядеть так: `int64 t = x + y; Check(t); t += z; Check(t); int result = t;`

Comment: @VladD Мне кажется, что это неизбежно.

Comment: @АлексейСаровский: Ну, если бы этот контроль можно было возложить на компилятор, было бы круто. Но это, судя по всему, не так уж легко. Хотя! Если это C++, можно написать классы-обёртки для `int` с перегруженными операциями. И использовать только их вместо `int`.

Comment: @VladD так там тоже после каждой операции придется проверять. Хотя... если важна скорость, можно попробовать опуститься ниже, сделать ассемблерную вставку и смотреть на флаг OF(CF)

Comment: @АлексейСаровский: Это да, но от пользователя хоть будет скрыто.

Comment: @АлексейСаровский Это если архитектура поддерживает такой флаг

Comment: @Mike Да, согласен. Но как ни крути, 99% программ пишется под 386-совместимые. Думаю эта не исключение.

Comment: дубликат http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/475960/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF-int-%D0%A1

Comment: @rikimaru2013 там ответ не подходит

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для проверки сложения что нибудь такое:

```
#include <limits.h>
int x = 12345;
int y = 67890;
if ((x > 0) && (y > INT_MAX - x)) ... Переполнение в положительную сторону
if ((x < 0) && (y < INT_MIN - x)) ... Переполнение в отрицательную
x+=y;
```

Аналогичные проверки надо сделать для других операций, т.е. вычитание проверять сложением, умножение - делением

Answer (score 4):

В [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html) и [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#checked-arithmetic-builtins) есть встроенные функции для арифметических операций с контролем переполнения.

Например вместо `x += y` можно написать

```
int tmp;
if (__builtin_add_overflow(x, y, &tmp)) {
    ... переполнение ...;
} else {
    x = tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться ассемблерной вставкой, например, так:

```
#include <stdio.h>

inline bool mult(int a, int b, int *c)
  {
  *c=a*b;

  _asm
    {
    jo FAIL
    }

  return true;
  FAIL: return false;
  }

int main(void)
  {
  int a, b, c;

  while(scanf("%d %d", &a, &b) == 2)
    printf("%d - %s\n", c, mult(a,b,&c)?"Ok":"Fail");

  return 0;
  }
```

http://bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?f=96&t=43748